# Column modification error shown.Code runs perfectly outside loop but fails inside loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, text, counter

Hi i am running a code but it's failing inside a loop but fails outside.
m['Count']=m['count']           "key error 'count' "
is the line it's failing at in the loop.

```
for i in range(1,len(dfn)):
    d=str(dfn.iloc[i]['Description'])
    table = string.maketrans("","")
    c=d.translate(None, string.punctuation)
    c= re.sub('[0-9]+', '', c)
    c=c.lower()
    word_tokens = word_tokenize(c) 
    filtered_sentence = [w for w in word_tokens if not w in stop_words] 
    filtered_sentence = []
    for w in word_tokens:
        if w not in stop_words:
            filtered_sentence.append(w) 
    b=Counter(filtered_sentence)
    m=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(b,orient='index')
    m= m.rename(columns={0: 'count'})
    print m.head()
    m['word']=m.index
    m.set_index('word', inplace=True)
    m['Count']=m['count']
    del m['count']
    m[m['Count']>1]=1
    a=pd.DataFrame({'Count': pd.concat([a,m], axis=1).fillna(0).sum(axis=1)})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If possible please provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- in the meantime, what is the error message you encounter?

Comment: It says "key error : 'count' "

Comment: Right before the error occurs, when you print m.head(), does the 'count' column exist?

Comment: For some reason it's not printing head :(...but this code is working perfectly when i add 2  dataframes for say i=0 and i=1 as in it's giving the perfect result and the lengths and values are all adding up

Comment: I believe there is something amiss with your "m" variable. If it is not printing head, there might be something wrong with it - try and print the type of "m" by: print "Type of m: " + str(type(m)) and see if the variable exists and is a working Dataframe.

Comment: My print doesn't work for some reason..i restarted the kernel and tried it..when i write print df.head() or even print "abc" there is no output but simply writing sf.head() is giving an output

Comment: Have you tried running your code in an IDE like Pycharm? It might give you a more detailed error message than the kernel and the <print> should definitely work...

Comment: import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
Then I've commented the second and third lines like this:

import sys
#reload(sys)
#sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")

Comment: The above solved the printing problem. Thanks sorry for disturbing

Comment: I'm glad to help - did that solve the above problem aswell?

Comment: Yes surprisingly !